# Get Image results from Google Image API returning invalid label (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, image, api

So I am trying to show x amount of images from google using the following code, but it keeps returning invalid label.  Does anyone have any ideas? thanks in advance for your help.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="google_images"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var iURL = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=kufa+castro&format=json&jsoncallback=?";
$.getJSON(iURL,function(json) {
    $(json).each(function() {
        $.each(json.results, function(i,item)
        {    
            //$("#google_images").append(item.unescapedUrl);
            $('#google_images').html();            
        });
    });
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone sees this, I changed this stuff up. ended up doing it this way: (could do blogs or images - BUT could do any other thing from Google api with some tweeking)

```
// return values from using Googles Image API
```

// search types (images,blogs)
// for posts (postUrl, titleNoFormatting)
// for images (unescapedUrl)
function google_search_api($search,$searchType,$count)
{

```
$url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/'.$searchType.'?v=1.0&q='.urlencode($search).'&filter=1';
if($searchType == "images"){
    //&rsz=large
    $url .="&safe=moderate";
}
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$url .="&userip=$ip&rsz=$count&key=".GOOGLE_API;
#echo $url;
$obj = json_decode( file_get_contents($url) );
foreach($obj->responseData->results as $i)
{
    // for images
    if($searchType == "images")
    {
        $source = "/timthumb.php?src=".$i->unescapedUrl."&a=t&h=75&w=75";
        //$source = $i->unescapedUrl;
        if (fopen($i->unescapedUrl, "r")) {
            echo "<li><img src=\"".$source."\" alt=\"".$search."\" width=\"75\" height=\"75\" /></li>";
        }
    }
    // for blogs
    else
    {
        //$title = mb_convert_encoding($i->titleNoFormatting, 'iso-8859-1');
        $title = mb_convert_encoding($i->titleNoFormatting, "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8");
        echo "<li><a href=\"".$i->postUrl."\" rel=\"external\"/>".$title."</a></li>";
    }
}
```

}
//USE: google_search_api('Jay Z','images','5')

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `jsonp` as `dataType`.

Have a look at this working: http://www.jsfiddle.net/FX79h/2/

Answer (score 0):

I changed the datatype to jsonp as shown below:

`dataType: 'jsonp'`

and `json.results` to `json.responseData.results` and it worked fine.

I have also used this to update my wordpress blog with relevant image based on the post title.

The code I used is as listed below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
var iURL = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images";
$.ajax({
    url: iURL,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {
        v:  '1.0',
        q:  $(".art-postheader").text(),
        format: 'json',
        jsoncallback:  '?'
    },
    success: callback
});
});

function callback(json){
    $("div.art-postcontent p:eq(2)")
.after("<img src='"
+json.responseData.results[0].unescapedUrl
+"' width='300px' align='left' />");
}
</script>
```

Comment: I removed your links, which looked like nothing but spam. Please do not add URLs to your posts just because you want people to go to your website. that's not how Stack Overflow works.